# Timed out waiting for page to load on a click event even though there is no page redirection

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, timeout

Getting `Timed out waiting for page to load` on a click event. The click event just opens the IE save prompt as mentioned in below screenshot. I handle this with Robot. It works. I am able to save a file but after that I am not able to do anything with driver instance. I get `Timed out waiting for page to load` error. And there is nothing actually waiting to be loaded. I should be able to move further.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This "open or save" dialog doesn't belong to any webpage; it's a system dialog which cannot be handled by Selenium. Robot or AutoIt can because they can access desktop or system component.